# In Tritium, what's the difference between add_class and attribute

Tags: moovweb, tritium

I can use add_class("classname") to add a class attribute to one of my elements, but I can also use attribute("class", "classname") to do the same.

What's the difference between the two functions? Any gotchas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, the tritium function `add_class(...)` will append the given argument to the class attribute in the node you're currently in (also prepending a space to separate it from other class names).

On the other hand, calling `attribute("class", "classname")` will actually clobber whatever class names already existed with the value you provided.

Below is an example illustrating both in tritium tester:

http://tritium.moovweb.com/43ecf5fdbc4bf6b07312372724df5a2522474cc3